# MVVM Toolkit light Messenger chained Messages

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

this might be complicated to explain but I give it a try...

I would like to use the Messenger to navigate to a new Page and also create a new Object (or pass one). How is this possible or am I on the wrong path?

Basically:
Click on "add new person" button which should bring up the PersonView and also should hold a new instance of a person object.

Click on "add person" button which should bring up the same PersonView page and should receives the object which is selected.

Message 1 = open Uri / Message 2 send exisiting or new object.

So far I have `MainPageViewModel` which sends

```
 Messenger.Default.Send<Uri>(...)...
```

And MainPage.cs which Registers `Messenger.Default.Register<Uri>(...)`and executes

```
Frame.Navigate(...targetUri)....
```

I tryed to Send a message to the PersonViewModel right after `Frame.Navigate`... but this runs out of sync... so the page was not loaded to receive the `PersonMessage`,...

So any tips, tricks, licks, approaches would be greate...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, basicaly it is a simple Singleton class that gets the navigation frame the page that contains, after that you are able to use it in your viewmodel and navigate, and get notified when the page changes, so with this you control in a better way the navigation
and send messages, and get aware about your page status.

---

public class NavigationFrameController {

```
    private static NavigationFrameController _instance;       
    private MainPage _root;
    public Frame NavFrame { get; set;}
    private static object keyLock = new Object();

    NavigationFrameController() {

        _root = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;
        NavFrame = _root.ContentFrame;
        NavFrame.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(ContentFrame_Navigated);
        NavFrame.NavigationFailed += new  NavigationFailedEventHandler(ContentFrame_NavigationFailed);

    }

    public static NavigationFrameController Instance {
        get {
            if (_instance == null)
                lock (keyLock) {
                  _instance = new NavigationFrameController();
               }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

     public void NavigateTo(Uri uri) {

        NavFrame.Source = uri;

    }

     private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
          //send your message
          // get attached to this event and get notified

     }

      private void ContentFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e) {
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Activating the screen works already... The kicker is to pass/or send an object right after launching the view

Comment: After the contentframe_navigated event you may send a message with your object, to the viewmodel that handles the page inside the frame, or you can encapsulate this event creating a new one for the class,  get notified and send the message , I did something like that and it worked, but I don't know if that fits your needs.Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - essentially where you receive the message to open a new window also create the viewmodel and add it to the view as datacontext.  When you instantiate your viewmodel pass in the existing object or null etc... then in your viewmodel you can handle whether its a new or existing object.

If you are using dependency injection then call a resolve from the codebehind where you process the 'add person' messsage etc..

Comment: I use ViewModelLocator centralized with Ninject. So on View creation the View knows automatically what ViewModel to bind to...

Comment: Correct - I use unity with viewmodel locator unless I need to pass a parameter via constructor then I use the method I described above.  This is not violating MVVM rules as the view is not created in viewmodel or anywhere other than view.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is keep the first message for navigation, and add to it the information about the object (person) you want to send. you can add a parameter to the query string, say "add=true" and then you can create the object normally in the view model, or the ID of the object to edit, and in this case, the viewmodel can retrieve the object itself and edit it.

To achieve this, in the code behind of the PersonView (associated with the PersonViewModel) has to send a message upon navigation (OnNavigatedTo) to its ViewModel containing the received info from the query string.